# Finding string that has repeated pattern in snowflake

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find the string that has repeated patterns in snowflake table. I am trying to get that using regex.

Example :
String : `'abc' , 'abcabc' ,  'snowsnowflake'`

The Query return  only  " 'abcabc' ,  'snowsnowflake' ". Because it has repeated patterns.

Thank you.

Comment: Try [`(.+)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/6ZwyIs/1)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with plain regex in SQL, but I was able to create a JavaScript UDF to get the desired results:

```sql
create or replace function find_repeated("x" string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
return x.match(/(.+)\1/g)
$$;

select x.value
  , find_repeated(x.value)
  , find_repeated(x.value) is not null has_repeated
from table(split_to_table('abc,abcabc,snowsnowflake', ',')) x
```

[image]